# How to access current FormControl from template

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 8 and Reactive Forms.

Inside my template, I have code that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" 
class="form-control" formControlName="name" 
placeholder="name" 
[class.is-invalid]="validationError(formControl)" />
```

The idea is that if validationError is "truthy", a red border is added to the input element.

Having trouble getting a reference to **FormControl** to be passed to the validationError function. Note that I have a lot of arrays in the form, so template references (i.e. #name) may be tricky. Is there a simple way to get a reference to the current form control, specified by formControlName, from the template?

Comment: What about using `form.get('name')`?

Comment: Also note that Angular automatically adds the class `ng-invalid` to the control. So simply adding a definition for this CSS class in your stylesheet would achieve the effect you want automatically, on all your inputs, without having to add anything to the template.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the control by getting it from the form.:

```
[class.is-invalid]="validationError(form.get('name'))"
```

Comment: This is the answer, the only thing to add is that it's common in angular form projects to create a getter for the formControl with getNameInput(){ return this.form.get('name')} so that at least you don't have form control names in your templates, yuck

Answer (score 3):

You can create a directive for this, injecting the NgControl, see:

Template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" appValidationError/>
```

Typescript:

```
...

import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appValidationError]'
})
export class ValidationError {

  @HostBinding('class.is-invalid') get isInvalid() { return this.ngControl.invalid; }

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

}
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to decorate with HostBinding a getter that simply returns `this.ngControl.invalid`

Comment: I believe that just using the HostBinding will not update the values ​​when they change